# Can I in opened partial view open another partial view select few values and pass them back to previous partial view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

The situation is as follow i have one already opened partial view - let's call it for example **User Details** in that view i have a button which clicked opens another partial view in modal window let's call it **User Roles** in that view i choose roles for user and click button to select roles - and that button close modal view and should pass the values of selected roles (id) to previous partial view where i can display them and submit changes on User

Already get the values in javascript (cause roles are displayed in Kendo Grid) and only think that is mysterious for me is how to pass these values to previous view.

Does anyone have solution or any ideas (examples) ?

Comment: When you close the model, assign the selected roles you want to javascript variables and the update the DOM with those inputs containing those values.

Comment: Thanks for answer, at this point a did something like this that i gather values and i put them into simple div in **User Details** view (thanks to that user can see what role names are selected, but now i want to put somewhere id numbers of selected roles to use them after submit in controller can i assing them to some kind of array that will be passed or simple hidden field from html helpers ?

Comment: Just add hidden inputs and set their values. You just need to ensure they are correctly named so they can be bound to your model on postback.